# Java SWT Print How to Print to File on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, printing, swt

I am trying to print a simple report using the code below. On Windows, this code works fine when attempting to print to PDF generator driver (instead of a real printer). But, on my Linux box, when I test the code below, the Linux print dialog opens but I do not seem to be able to capture the print to file filename. The problem that this creates is the report is printed using print-to-file to the current executing directory rather than to the location specified in the Print Dialog. (I want to user to be able to print-to-file and specify the location.)

NOTE: This code uses some test print statements to determine the PrintDialog file path information--that is, I realize that I do not use this information.

**Code Snippet**

```
        PrintDialog printdialog = new PrintDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), SWT.NONE);
        PrinterData printerdata = printdialog.open ();
        if (printerdata.printToFile) {
            System.out.println("TESTING 2013-10-09:: " + printerdata.fileName) ;

        }

        if (printerdata != null) {

            ReportHeader header = new ReportHeader("Preprocessing Errors Report", true) ;  
            ReportFooter footer = new ReportFooter() ;

            // Create styled text for the report text itself
            StyledTextPrint reporttext = new StyledTextPrint() ;
            TextStyle reporttextstyle = new TextStyle().fontHeight(ReportDefaults.REPORTFONTSIZE) ;
            reporttext.append("Preprocessing Errors Report\n\n" + 
                    "Matter Name: " + systemprefs.getMatterName(systemprefs.getCurrentMatter()) +
                    "\n[" + systemprefs.getCurrentMatter() + "]\n\n" +              
                    TextLineSplitter.splitline(printablereporttext.toString(), 55).toString(), reporttextstyle) ;

            // Use page print to print all the formatted text
            PagePrint text = new PagePrint(
                    header, 
                    ReportDefaults.HEADERBOTTOMMARGIN, 
                    reporttext, 
                    ReportDefaults.FOOTERBOTTOMMARGIN, 
                    footer);

            ScalePrint stext = new ScalePrint(text) ;

            // Perform actual printing
            String reportfilename = "PreprocessingErrorsReport" + systemprefs.getCurrentMatter() ;
            PaperClips.print(new PrintJob(reportfilename, stext), printerdata) ;
```

**Other Info:**

- Uses Java SWT Paperclips for simple printing.
  https://code.google.com/p/swt-paperclips/
- Java 7
- List item

Linux Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: If you want to create a pdf, why the detour with `PrintDialog`?

Comment: I apologize. The PDF mention was a red herring. I DO need to print to file. On Windows (where I did most of the initial testing), I used the PDF print driver to simulate a print-to-file. On Linux, this does not work. I get nothing back from the PrintDialogue on Linux. In other words, if the enduser selects print a report, the Print Dialog should appear to permit printing. But on Linux, you can print to file (rather than a real printer) to specify the location where you want the print to be saved.

Comment: So you don't actually want to print to a printer, you just want to create a file? If so what do you want to save to the file?

Comment: I think this is getting confused. What should happen is when I select Print from my application (via a SWT Button), the PrintDialog appears. The user can then select a printer. On Linux, however, the user can also print-to-file. If selecting the latter, the print job should print to the selected filename and file path in the PrintDialog. But,I cannot figure out how to get this filename and filepath from the Linux PrintDialog to send to the print function. In other words, in the unique case where the Linux user prints to file, I cannot now print to that file. (Ignore the issue for Windows.)